# Fear Street Trilogy - Are the characters from the sequels reincarnations or descendants?

Tags: fear-street

Related to the [Fear Street movies trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fear_Street_Trilogy) released on Netflix. Spoilers Ahead!!!

The three movies in release order take place in **1994**, **1978** and **1666** respectively.

> It's revealed at the end that **Nick Goode** from 1994 is a descendant of **Solomon Goode** from 1666.

Also, we can see the same actor/actress playing different roles in different movies of this trilogy. For example, **Simon Kalivoda** in the first movie (1994) and **Issac** in the last movie (1666) is played by the same actor. The same with **Kate Schmidt** in 1994 and **Lizzie** in 1666. There seems to be a deeper connection rather than recasting the same people for different roles.

The prominent examples are the sibling connections. 1994, **Deena Johnson** has a brother named **Josh**, and in 1666, **Sarah Fier** (which is shown as Deena re-living her story) has a brother named **Henry**; both versions played by same actress/actor duo. Another example is the two actresses playing sisters **Cindy** and **Christine(Ziggy) Berman** from 1978 also play the sisters **Abigail** and **Constance** from 1666. Apart from that, Deena is in love with **Sam** in 1994 and Sarah is in love with **Hannah** in 1666, where Sam and Hannah are played by the same actress.

My question is, are all these characters from 1994 and 1978 **reincarnations or descendants** (ignoring Nick Goode, which is obvious) of their 1666 selves?